# js variable value in a function from which scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, local

i have this code in java script

```
var x = 5;
function f(y) { return (x + y) - 2 };
function g(h) { var x = 7; return h(x) };
{ var x = 10; z = g(f) };
```

z value is 15. why?
the expression (x+y)-2 is being evaluated as (10+7)-2.
why does x get the value of 10, and not the value of the previous
block, where x = 7?
thanks for the help

Comment: you have an unusual block at the end ...

Comment: Your code has missing semicolons.

Comment: @mike Oh cmon... I invested all of my brain power in writing my answer and you copied the question??

Comment: i am sorry! i had no knowledge of this other post.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely delete the first assignment. It gets overwritten before you call `g(f)`.

Also, you can remove the parentheses of the last block as there is no block scope in JS (actually block scope got introduced with `let`, so you wanna use that instead).

```
var x = 5;

function f(y) { 
    // global variable x is 10 -> 10 + 7 - 2 = 15
    return (x + y) - 2; 
}

function g(h) { 
    // x gets declared locally - local value will be used
    var x = 7;   
    return h(x); // f gets called with y = 7
}

x = 10; //global x gets changed
z = g(f);
```

... and always place your semicolons. Even though they maybe look optional but in some cases they are obligatory.

Answer (score 1):

Value of variable x is 10 at global execution context.
When function f is finally called the value of the argument which is y, this y actually represent value of x at local execution context of function g, here x is 7.

```
       var x = 5;
        function f(y) {
         return (x + y) - 2 ;  
          }; // value of global var x is 10, value of parameter passed is 7
            // this value comes from the local var x of g function's  execution context.

        function g(h) { 
        var x = 7; return h(x); };

       { var x = 10; z = g(f); };

       console.log(z);
```